# WAP push messages in android

Tags: android

Anybody know which permission is used for receiving the WAP push messages in android ?
and please let me know its description also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.html

http://blog.mediarain.com/2011/03/simple-google-android-c2dm-tutorial-push-notifications-for-android/

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try:

```
<intent-filter>
                                <action
android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED" />
                        <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.sic" />
                        </intent-filter>
```

There is differing information about the specific support in various versions of Android for WAP Push, so let me know if that works for you.